# Looking for advice on creating Tidy data from the start

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse

I have a data set that will be growing. It is categorical observations (i.e., 1=yes, 2=no) by date and hour. Is the following an acceptable method of formatting for import to R or is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: What do the two observations here represent? Are they a count of vessels seeing no fish and a count of those seeing fish, or will there potentially be more than two rows per hour?

Comment: No, it is a whether a vessel was observed in the data and whether a fish was observed in the data. Each is binary (either vessel was seen or not).

Comment: That might be a perfectly acceptable method. "Tidy" data should have one observation per row, one variable per column. If the data here is showing two observations, one detecting vessels and fish, one detecting just vessels, then this seems appropriate. https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

Comment: I would make the month, day, year and hour a single date/time column.  If that is too much work you could have R code add that later if it can be assumed that there are exactly 24 hours per date.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yeah, when you have 24 hours per day. 30 days a month, and processing 4 months at a time, it gets time consuming to build the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a template like this:

[image]

Using one column for the date makes it much easier to read/import into R.  Also, the YYYY-MM-DD is the default format in R for date columns.  Trying to write date and hour together in one column could be done but seems like it could be tedious and not as easy to see what is going on in the data.  As was mentioned in the comments above, each observation should be on a separate row.  Once you save the data as a csv, it will be easily imported into R.
Good luck.

Comment: Would this be easy to analyze by month in R?

Comment: Yes.  In R, it is very easy to make a new column using the imported data with Year-Month (using the `format(Date, "%Y-%m")` function)  .  Then you can do almost any type of analysis you want by month.

Comment: Actually if you are using Excel to create this then if you create two date times and then select them and drag that down it will complete the regular sequence for you so it seems as easy to do in Excel as in R.